# Quickbooks Web Connector parsererror when trying to do AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, file-get-contents, quickbooks

Using Keith Palmer's Classes for Quickbooks, located here:  https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

I am now getting a parse error being returned from the Quickbooks Web Connector App.

Basically, I am performing an AJAX Request like so:

```
$('.form-item').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
        $index = $this.data('index'),
        $company = $('input.company-' + $index).val(),
        $status = $this.data('status');

    // Current Action/Status being performed here!
    console.log(current_action);
    console.log($status);

    var data = {
        action: 'hunter_' + current_action,
        security: HUNTER_admin[current_action + '_nonce'],
        form: $this.serialize(), // serialize the form data
        company: $company
    };

    // Might need to create Customer
    if (current_action == 'create_estimate')
    {
        // This returns an array of current emails in the database and QB
        data['qb_emails'] = HUNTER_admin.emails;
    }

    console.dir(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: HUNTER_admin.ajax_url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    }).done(function(response) {
        alert('Success');
        $('.' + $status + '-' + $index).replaceWith($('<div />').html(response.statustext));

    }).always(function(response) {
        console.dir(response);
    });
```

And now for the ajax within my `functions.php` file of wordpress:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_hunter_create_estimate', 'hunter_create_estimate');

function hunter_create_estimate()
{
    global $wpdb;

    check_ajax_referer('create-estimate', 'security');
    $response = array();

    if (!current_user_can('manage_options'))
    {
        return $response;
        die();
    }
    require_once(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/QuickBooks.php');

    // Get All data!
    parse_str($_POST['form'], $data);

    // Check current emails in quickbooks and see if a match is found with users email, to determine if we need to create a New Customer in Quickbooks or not:

    $qb_emails = !empty($_POST['qb_emails']) ? array_map('strtolower', $_POST['qb_emails']) : array();

    if (empty($qb_emails) || !in_array(strtolower($data['email']), $qb_emails))
    {
        $data['has_email'] = false;

        // Email not set within the database, so we need to add this customer to the quickbooks Queue!
        $dsn = 'mysqli://' . DB_USER . ':' . DB_PASSWORD . '@' . DB_HOST . '/' . DB_NAME;
        $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
        $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER);

    }
    else
        $data['has_email'] = true;


    // Now fire up the Queue that will Add the Estimate!

    $response = array_merge($data, array('company' => $_POST['company'], 'statustext' => '<p class="text">Creating Estimate...</p>', 'emails' => $_POST['qb_emails']));

    echo json_encode($response);

    die();
}
```

Everything was fine until I connected the Quickbooks.php file and called a queue.  Now I am getting a Parser error during Submission and Responses from Quickbooks.

I'm actually just trying to test a `QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER` call:

My map array looks like this:

```
$map = array(
    QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),
    QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER => array('_quickbooks_query_customer_request', '_quickbooks_query_customer_response'),
);
```

The 2 functions look like this:

```
function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    $arr = array(
        'name' => 'Doe Enterprises',
        'fname' => 'John',
        'lname' => 'Doe'
    );

    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="11.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CustomerAddRq>
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <CompanyName>' . $arr['name'] . '</CompanyName>
                        <FirstName>' . $arr['fname'] . '</FirstName>
                        <LastName>' . $arr['lname'] . '</LastName>
                    </CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}

function _quickbooks_customer_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{
    global $theme_dir;

    $data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA)), true);
    file_put_contents($theme_dir . '/customer_response.txt', 'ListID = ' . mysql_escape_string($idents['ListID']) . PHP_EOL . var_export($data, true) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . 'idents' . PHP_EOL . var_export($idents, true), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Only Error I am getting from Quickbooks is as follows:

> 0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML
>   text stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove this line:

> // parse error somewhere in here, need to investigate this!
>   require_once(trailingslashit(get_home_path()) . 'server.php');

You can not test like this. The *Web Connector* should call server.php. YOU SHOULD NOT.

You can do your queuing via AJAX, but the actual processing of the qbXML requests/server components need to be triggered by the Web Connector, not by you.

Notice how the examples in the documentation of how to queue stuff up DO NOT call any of the server components:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_queueing.php

Comment: Right so, I have changed it to require the `Quickbooks.php` file instead.  My mistake.  However, there is a `parseerror` still in the Quickbooks App when the xml gets sent and parsed.  All I am able to get is `Error Number 0x80040400
QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.`

Comment: I updated the Question with the changes, can you take a look at my changes.  I do believe the code should work fine now.  But parse error still occurs.

Comment: Go look at the QuickBooks OSR reference. The [Name] field is very specifically marked REQUIRED.

Comment: Thanks, all working now, can't believe I missed that!  But than again, feeling kinda dumb on many things here.  Thanks for pointing me in the right place.